# Maps API search with areas/polygons to find everything inside area

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, maps, geocoding

I need your help.
I'm developing a site where I need a search like the google maps search feature, but with the feature of searching with areas.

Example.
Let's say I'm building a site to show all houses for sale in a country.
I use the google maps api to get a point on a map, and see all "houses for sale" around this point. This is all good, and the way I wan't to do it.

But, I have an "email agent", for my customers to get similar houses in the area.
How can I bind the first map search, to a specific area.

Google maps, shows some "boundaries/polygon" data on their map defining a single area like "Manhattan, New York", I wan't these kind of data, but it doesn't seem to be available.

So in short, I need help to figure out the best way and the best maps provider, for a search site where the "owner" can set a house for sale, the "buyers" can search for houses for sale, and get notifications when a house in their preferred areas(e.g. Manhattan) is uploaded to the site.

I was thinking doing it by the areas/boundaries/polygons, or another way by the given searchers point and an estimated search radius of 5-10km.